# Creating Temporary Column Order By Slow

Tags: mysql, performance

So basically what I'm trying to do is get gained experience, ordering it, then only displaying top 5 or 50. Now note that I'm not SQL expert but I have knowledge of indexes as well as file sorting. The query that I have is filesorting most likely due to "gained_xp" not being a index-- let alone even a column as it's only temporary. There's no clear explanation how to fix this as I'm trying to contain it all in one query. I'm trying to sort nearly 13k rows with that number only expanding. I'd also need the number of rows to be dynamic as well as the time since. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Explain Output: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Indexes include: time userid override overallXp overallLevel overallRank

The closest I've gotten to order all rows (which never ends up completing and ends in a mysql reboot) are:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m-%d'), t_u.userid as uid, MAX(t_u.OverallXP)-(SELECT overallXP FROM track_updates WHERE `userid` = t_u.userid AND `time`>'1394323200' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) as gained_xp
FROM track_updates t_u
WHERE t_u.time>'1394323200'
GROUP BY t_u.userid
```

If I'd run a query that selects only one user and works correctly is:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m-%d'), (t_u.overallXP)-(SELECT overallXP FROM track_updates WHERE `userid`='1' ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1) as gained_xp, t_u.userid
FROM track_updates t_u
WHERE t_u.userid='1' AND t_u.time>'1393632000'
ORDER BY t_u.time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

Sample Data per request:

```
 ____________________________________________________________________
| id | userid | time        | overallLevel | overallXP | overallRank |
| 1  | 1      | 1394388114  | 1            | 1         | 1           |
| 2  | 1      | 1394389114  | 2            | 10        | 1           |
| 3  | 2      | 1394388114  | 1            | 1         | 2           |
| 4  | 2      | 1394389114  | 1            | 5         | 2           |
| 5  | 2      | 1394390114  | 2            | 7         | 2           |
```

---

Output (most recent time; gained xp current-initial; ordered by gain_xp):

```
 ____________________________________________
| id | time             | userid | gained_xp |
| 1  | March 9th 2014   | 1      | 9         |
| 2  | March 9th 2014   | 2      | 6         |
```

Comment: I'd suggest to provide exact table schema, sample data and the desired output based on that sample data

Comment: @peterm Thank you for your suggestion-- I've added what you requested.

Comment: You should look at the `EXPLAIN` output (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`).

Comment: @ceejayoz Right it's saying that gained_xp is using filesort which is due to it not having an index. I've added it to my original post for clarity.